# Displaying data from two tables in Yii CGridView

Tags: php, yii

I want to show 2 tables with a right join, but the code I wrote does not work as expected. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

view : admin.php

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'id' => 'punish-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->searchJoin(),
    'type' => 'striped bordered condensed',
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'header' => 'No',
                'type'=>'raw',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 25px'),
                'value'=>'$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage
                       *$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize + $row+1',
            ),
            // i want to display p.kode,p.status from table status
            'berlaku_punish',
            'nilai',
            array(
                'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
            ),
        ),
));
```

and my model : BasePunish.php

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'idStatus' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Status', 'id_status'),
    );
}

public function searchJoin() {
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select = 'p.kode,p.status,t.nilai,t.berlaku_punish';
    $criteria->join= 'RIGHT JOIN status p ON (t.id_status=p.id)';
    $criteria->condition = 't.id_status IS NULL';

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
            'sort'=>array(
                    'defaultOrder'=>'kode ASC',
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might really did not understand what you are asking but still if nothing is working for you then you can try this

```
array(
'header'=>'Products',
'value'=>array($model,'gridCreateUser'),
),
```

In this, the **value** will try to find the function **gridCreateUser** in the class of which **$model** is the object. In your case i guess $model is the object of the **BasePunish.**

So in your **BasePunish.php** create a function **gridCreateUser()** and then you can return the value which you want to display in your widget. 
eg:-
In your **BasePunish.php**

```
public function gridCreateUser($data)
{
// you can access the object $data here
// do what ever you want to do
$value='return whatever you want to return';
return $value;
// this $value will be displayed there
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've done like you advice, but still visible null data.

Comment: This means that the issue is with your query. have you tried executing query separately?

Comment: try turning logging on to see what query is executed exactly, and compare that to the query you are expecting to get.

Comment: I wrote : $criteria->select = '`s`.`kode` , `s`.`status` , `t`.`berlaku_punish` , `t`.`nilai`';
$criteria->join = 'RIGHT JOIN status s ON (t.id_status=s.id)';
How to show s.kode and s.status in cgridview??